# C program acting weird

Tags: c, gcc

I've started implementing a circular queue in C, and I have the following lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cirq.h"

//allocate a circular queue
cirq cq_alloc(void){
  cirq cq = NULL;
  element *head;
  element *tail;

  if((head = malloc(sizeof(struct element*))) &&
      (tail = malloc(sizeof(struct element *)))){
    head->content = 0; // head node keeps track of size.
    tail->content = NULL;
    head->next = tail;
    tail->next = head;
    cq = &head;
  } else {
    printf("ERROR: No space for more cqueues.\n");
  }
  return cq;
}

int cq_size(cirq q){
  return (int)(*q)->content;
}

int main(){
  cirq q = cq_alloc();
  printf("Size of element ptr %lu\n", sizeof(struct element *));
  printf("%d\n", cq_size(q));
  return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile and run this program, having commented out the line in `main` that prints out `sizeof(struct element *))`, the program runs fine and I get the right size of the queue, 0. When I leave the line in, the size of the `struct` is printed out, but after that I get a `segmentation fault: 11`. Also, to make things clear, the `struct element` has `void *data` and `struct element *next` fields. How can adding in a line that prints stuff change the behavior of the program so much?

EDIT: `cirq.h`

```
#ifndef CIRQ_H
#define CIRQ_H
typedef struct element **cirq; // cirq handle

typedef struct element {
  void *content;
  struct element *next;
} element;

extern cirq cq_alloc(void);// allocate a queue
extern int cq_size(cirq q);// return the size of a queue
extern void cq_enq(cirq q, void *value);// add a value to the queue
extern void *cq_deq(cirq q);// dequeue and return a queue value
extern void *cq_peek(cirq q);// return the value at the queue head
extern void cq_rot(cirq q);// requeue the head element at the tail
extern void cq_free(cirq q);// return all space allocated to queue
#endif
```

Comment: It's called undefined behavior and it's a bi**h. Your `if ((head = malloc() ...` could cause a memory leak. It's not good style and it doesn't improve readability, it's terrible actually (*this is actually constructive, it's advice*).

Comment: That's incomplete, please read [ask]

Comment: Can you show the definitions of `criq` and `element`? (If it's not too much: the entire contents of `cirq.h`)

Comment: Sure! I mentioned `element` at the end of my question, and `cirq` is defined as `struct element **cirq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what `cirq` is, the fact that you return the address of a local object is the problem.

This here

```
cq = &head;
```

is causing the *undefined behavior*, because that's the address of the pointer `head` which is stored locally in the function only, when the function returns it's deallocated and thus invalid. Using it elsewhere (*outside the function*) is *Undefined Behavior*.

Also, do not `typedef` a pointer. Never do that, let the code reader know that **it is a pointer**.

Comment: I could not have wished for a better answer! I made `head` and `tail` global variables, and the undefined behavior stopped. Thanks pal!

Comment: @modsoussi That's like saying putting your head in the gas oven has cured your headache. What happens if you want two 'circ' objects???

Comment: @modsoussi Terrible solution! Also, you can't tell whether the undefined behavior stopped, it's undefined and sometimes you don't even know that it's there.

Comment: @Roddy would it make more sense then to define `cirq` as a `struct` with `head` and `tail` fields rather than as a double pointer? Or @iharob just return `&head`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad smell:

```
if((head = malloc(sizeof(struct element*))) &&
```

You're mallocing the size of a *pointer*. I think you meant to malloc the struct itself...?

Comment: You're right, I did mean to malloc the struct itself!